# Is there a better way than crypto.randomBytes to generate unique ids in performance-wise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js documentation strongly discourages the usage of `crypto.randomBytes()`. However as I read in an answer of StackOverflow, in all methods of random string generation such as using timestamps etc. the best way to achieve highest entropy is `crypto.randomBytes()`.

I would like to use this uuid strategy to generate validation keys in my node.js system. Is there any other better way performance-wise?

Comment: performance wise? its always expensive on the CPU afaik

Comment: Why do you need a high entropy for your unique ids? And shouldn't it be enough to seed a random generator from the high-entropy source?

Comment: Where exactly does the documentation strongly discourage the usage of it?

Comment: @FINDarkside as I remember https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Comment: Doesn't discourage it anymore at least. I don't think this question can be answered if there's no source for the claim. I'd assume they'd give a reason when discouraging something.

Comment: @FINDarkside as I remember it was discouraged because randomBytes blocks the I/O when there is not enough entropy. That's why on another page they say it is/should run by a worker thread, I don't remember which. The doc page with the claim was very old so maybe they changed it recently.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use CSPRNG, not really.

Using `uuid` was suggested, but it simply calls `crypto.randomBytes(16)` and converts it to hex string. `randomBytes` blocking isn't really a problem, because it offers asynchronous api as well (second arg is callback). When generating such small amounts of data, using the sync api might be faster though.

Docs [do still mention](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) lack of entropy possibly causing longer block than usual. It should only be a problem right after boot though and even in that case blocking can be avoided by using the asynchronous api.

> The crypto.randomBytes() method will not complete until there is sufficient entropy available. This should normally never take longer than a few milliseconds. The only time when generating the random bytes may conceivably block for a longer period of time is right after boot, when the whole system is still low on entropy.